# Why does this code not invoke the no-argument constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

Suppose I define the class `Box` as follows:

```
class Box {
public:
  Box(int volume) : m_volume(volume) {}

private:
  int m_volume;
};
```

Obviously `Box` does not have  a no-argument constructor defined. However, the following code will still compile:

```
Box box = Box(1);
```

I thought that the above statement 1) created a `Box` object using the no-argument constructor; 2) created a `Box` object using the `Box(int)` constructor; and 3) set `box` to equal the previously created `Box` object using the default copy assignment operator. If this reasoning were correct, the code would not compile because step 1 cannot be executed.

So what's going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So what's going on?

You're being wrong. :)

> I thought that the above statement 1) created a Box object using the no-argument constructor; 2) created a Box object using the Box(int) constructor; and 3) set box to equal the previously created Box object using the default copy assignment operator.

No. It does (2) then copy-constructs the named object using the temporary as its argument.<sup>†</sup> There is no assignment here at all.

The code is equivalent to the much clearer:

```
Box box{Box(1)};
```

The equals-syntax is basically provided for familiarity since we traditionally initialise built-ins using `=`, even though that's not "assignment" either.

That's why some people don't do this:

```
int i = 42;
```

but instead this:

```
int i(42);
```

or this:

```
int i{42};
```

(We'll ignore the sillies who write `auto i = int(42)` or `auto i{int(42)}`.)

Of course in reality you should be writing:

```
Box box(1);
```

<sub><sup>†</sup> The copy-construction can actually be "optimised" away by the compiler, producing code actually equivalent to just `Box box(1)`; however, the copy-construction is required to be possible anyway.</sub>

Comment: Or it gets elided and there is just a construction.

Comment: I do love your answers, Lightness :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Me too! :D

Comment: @NathanOliver: I originally decided to abstract that away but forgot that as-if isn't involved here so I have put in a note.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: it can be elided but still copy ctor must be accessible otherwise program is ill formed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I saw that.  As always great job and thanks for adding the extra information.

Comment: @PravasiMeet Although it may be made mandatory [in the future](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html).

Comment: @TartanLlama: Oh no :( A proposal to cater to the sillies!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: why?